# PHP: Write values of associative array in a column of CSV file based on their keys

Tags: php, csv

I have this associative array with a key "key1" and another "key2":

```
{   
   id   :   1,
   name : "Rob",
   key1 : "bla"
},
{   
   id   :   2,
   name : "Mat",
   key1 : "blabla"
},
{   
   id   :   3,
   name : "Tom",
   key2 : "blablabla"
}
```

this is my code for write the csv file:

```
    // $csv is the array

    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'wb');

    foreach ($csv as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

result is something like. All the information in line:

```
1,Rob,bla
2,Mat,blabla
3,Tom,blablabla
```

Is there a way to write these values in the column based on their key? The result should be:

```
id  |  name  |  key1    |   key2
1   |  Rob   |  bla     |
2   |  Mat   |  blabla  |
3   |  Tom   |          |  blablabla
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a loop saving all your table keys. Then you check all the keys on each line, if the key is missing, create it with an empty string !

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'wb');
$savedKeys = [] ;
foreach ($csv as $getKey) {
$savedKeys = array_merge($savedKeys,array_keys($getKey)) ;
}

$savedKeys =array_unique($savedKeys) ;

foreach ($csv as $fields) {

    foreach ($savedKeys AS $checkKey){
        if (!isset($field[$checkKey])){
            $field[$checkKey] = '';
        }
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: In my case, I wanted to have the header in the CSV. So I had to write to the CSV after $savedKeys where unique: `fputcsv($fp, $savedKeys, $separator = ";", $enclosure = "\"");`
The data-`fputcsv` then accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed this, and implemented as follows:

```php
<?php

class DisparateRowAlignerTest extends TestCase {

  public function test_aligning_disparate_rows() {
    $this->assertEquals(
      [
        ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'zip'],
        [1, '', '', ''],
        [2, 3, '', ''],
        ['', 5, 4, ''],
        [6, '', 7, ''],
        ['', '', '', 8],
        ['', '', '', ''],
      ],
      DisparateRowAligner::alignRows([
        ['foo' => 1],
        ['foo' => 2, 'bar' => 3],
        ['baz' => 4, 'bar' => 5],
        ['foo' => 6, 'baz' => 7],
        ['zip'=> 8],
        [],
      ])
    );
  }

}

class DisparateRowAligner {

  /**
   * @param array<array<string, mixed>> $rows
   */
  public static function alignRows(
    array $rows,
    ?string $emptyFill = ''
  ): array {
    $keys = static::getKeys($rows);
    return [
      $keys,
      ...array_map(
        fn (array $oldRow) => array_map(
          fn (string $key) => $oldRow[$key] ?? $emptyFill,
          $keys
        ),
        $rows
      ),
    ];
  }

  private static function getKeys(array $rows): array {
    return array_values(
      array_unique(
        array_reduce(
          $rows,
          fn (array $keys, array $row) => array_merge($keys, array_keys($row)),
          []
        )
      )
    );
  }

}
```